# Android: How to implement a variable subscription start date Google in App subscriptions

Tags: java, android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I am implementing a subscription in my app. All my users get 30days trial by default handled by my own scripts. I am trying to implement Google IAP for my app and basically want the Subscription to start when the trial ends (date from my db) or delay the start by a variable amount of day that add up to the trial end date.

I am wondering if this possible or of anyone has pointers to accomplish this.

I am using https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

and this is my create billing methods:

```
    public void startBilling() {
        bp = new BillingProcessor(this, getResources().getString(R.string.play_console_license), this);
        bp.initialize();
        onBillingInitialized();
    }

    public void onBillingInitialized() {

//        Log.d("MainActivity", "onBillingInitialized: ");

        String premium = getResources().getString(R.string.premium);

        TransactionDetails purchaseTransactionDetails = bp.getSubscriptionTransactionDetails(premium);
        bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();

        SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String ident = pref.getString("ident", null);

        bp.subscribe(this, premium, ident);

    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it by your own.

The only way to achieve this is by using the [free trial](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/subscriptions#ft-ip) option and configure it for 30 days (you can't make this period variable). If you want a variable period of time for your free trial, you should create as many IAP as your periods (one IAP with a 1-day-free-trial, ... one IAP with a 30-day-free-trial), but I wouldn't recommend it.

Good chance with your implementation, In-App Subscriptions aren't easy ^^

Comment: Ah okay thats for the clarification. Yeah I may just implement a buffer in my script so if a user buys the sub within the trail then save the remaining in column with a end date with that factored in. 

Yh not easy at all espacially when the its multiplatform so I have google, apple and stripe to deal with

Comment: Yep, such a nightmare implementing so many platforms :/ If my answer solved your issue, don't hesitate to accept it.